# geom_abline doesn't recognize scale_color_manual colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale-color-manual

I have disparate datasets I'm bringing together with ggplot. I can get the colors for lines and legend to work with geom_line, but not geom_abline. For example, this works:

```
df1 <- data.frame(year=c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994),
                  varA=c(10.1, 12.2, 9.7, 11.2, 10.5))

df2 <- data.frame(year=c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994),
                  varB=c(900, 780, 889, 910, 820))


cols <- c("varA" = "#D55E00", "varB" = "#0072B2", "varC" = "#D55E00")

g1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=df1,
            aes(x=year, y=varA, color="varA"), 
            linewidth=1) +
  geom_line(data=df2,
            aes(x=year, y=varB/100, color="varB"), 
            linewidth=1) +
  scale_color_manual(name=NULL,
                     values=cols,
                     labels=c("Variable A", "Variable B")
  )

g1
```

[image]

But when I try to add geom_abline, it doesn't recognize the named color:

```
varC_coef <- coef(lm(varA*0.2 ~ year, data = df1))

g2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=df1,
            aes(x=year, y=varA, color="varA"), 
            linewidth=1) +
  geom_line(data=df2,
            aes(x=year, y=varB/100, color="varB"), 
            linewidth=1) +
  geom_abline(intercept=varC_coef[1], 
              slope=varC_coef[2], 
              colour="varC") +
  scale_color_manual(name=NULL,
                     values=cols,
                     labels=c("Variable A", "Variable B", "Variable C")
  )

g2
```

I get this error:

```
> g2
Error in `geom_abline()`:
! Problem while converting geom to grob.
ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error:
! Unknown colour name: varC
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
>
```

Any ideas what the problem/solution is?

TIA

Update:

Applying some of the suggestions so far from comments, I've gotten this far. I changed it to not use scale_color_manual at all and added scale_y_continuous so the geom_abline shows up on the graph. Even though I explicitly set "show.legend = TRUE", it's not showing up in the legend. ??

```
g2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=df1,
            aes(x=year, y=varA, color="#D55E00"), 
            linewidth=1) +
  geom_line(data=df2,
            aes(x=year, y=varB/100, color="#0072B2"), 
            linewidth=1) +
  geom_abline(intercept=varC_coef[1], 
              slope=varC_coef[2], 
              colour="black",
              show.legend=TRUE) +
  # scale_color_manual(name=NULL,
  #                    values=cols,
  #                    labels=c("Variable A", "Variable B", "Variable C")
  # ) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 13))

g2
```

[image]

Comment: I think it's because for `geom_abline`, your aesthetics are not inherited from the dataframe that you're using with `geom_line`. Those aesthetics connect to `scale_color_manual`, but `geom_abline` doesn't make that connection. (From `geom_abline` help page: "Unlike most other geoms, these geoms do not inherit aesthetics from the plot default.") Although note that even if you change to call to `colour="black"`, which does prevent the error, your line doesn't actually show up on the plot, which I don't really understand.

Comment: Where did the 0.2 come from in the equation: `varA*0.2 ~ year`?

Comment: @C.Murtaugh It's because that specific `abline` is way off the plot. `1990 * -0.004 + 10 = 2.04`, which is far below the y axis range. @e-maas, what do you get if you add `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 13)) +` somewhere in the middle of your ggplot statements? I think this is also what @Dave2e is saying.

Comment: You might consider the information at `?col2rgb`. The examples are all using "colors" values that are in the default palette. Perhaps ypou need to convert your rgb strings to something that the `scale_color_manual` function recognizes as a palette value?

Comment: @Dave2e, it's just a random equation to produce a line for this example.

Comment: @David, even though it's much lower, why wouldn't the y-axis change scale to include it? But I did add scale_y_continuous as you suggested, and the line did show up, replacing ```color="black"``` in the geom_abline. But it's still not in the legend, which is based on the scale_color_manual, which the geom_abline doesn't participate in.

Comment: @IRTFM, they are colorblind palette colors. I did notice something in the scale_color_manual documentation about the colorspace package, using the viridis type. I'll look into that.

Comment: @C.Murtaugh, I thought that aesthetics inheritance was based on it being defined at the top level:  ```ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, etc.))``` . But the aesthetics here are defined separately for each geom_line as well as geom_abline. So I guess I still don't understand what the limitation is.

Comment: @EMaas Okay - if you replace your call with `geom_abline(aes(color='varC', intercept=varC_coef[1], slope=varC_coef[2]), show.legend=F)`, that does work. Although it still requires you to separately specify a lower y-limit in order to see it, as pointed out by David. Why? [shrug emoji]

Comment: @EMaas, in the `geom_abline` reference page, it says that these ablines "do not affect the x and y scales." I'm guessing that they don't update the legends either. Something else to try: `show_guide=TRUE` in the `geom_abline` call. There is a package that has `geom_abline2` which does rescale the axes to include the abline (package is `jaspGraphs`, but I have never used it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that geom_abline isn't the best choice for this particular application. To summarize the very helpful comments, geom_abline neither inherits aesthetics from the plot default nor re-scales the y-axis to include itself if it falls outside the range defined by the earlier geom_lines. Even though no aesthetics were set in the top-level ggplot() line, the inheritance comes from the scale_color_manual statement, which uses the named vector "cols". Geom_abline does not participate in those settings.

In order to get the outcome I needed, I switched geom_abline to geom_smooth. This does inherit aesthetics, contributes to the y-axis range, and allows seamless inclusion into the legend. This code works:

```
cols <- c("varA" = "#D55E00", "varB" = "#0072B2", "varC" = "#882255")

g3 <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=df1,
            aes(x=year, y=varA, color="varA"), 
            linewidth=1) +
  geom_line(data=df2,
            aes(x=year, y=varB/100, color="varB"), 
            linewidth=1) +
  geom_smooth(data=df1,
              aes(color="varC",
                  x=year,
                  y=varA*0.2),
              se=FALSE,
              method=lm) +
  scale_color_manual(name=NULL,
                     values=cols,
                     labels=c("Variable A", "Variable B","Variable C")
  )

g3
```

[image]

Comment: You don't have to use `geom_smooth()` if you use a data frame to call `geom_abline()`.  It depends on how you arrive at your slope/intercept.  If you're using `lm()` or another regression function to define your slope and intercept, then `geom_smooth()` makes sense, but if you want to do that "outside" of the `ggplot()` function, you should use `geom_abline()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since color is already mapped in aesthetics with `geom_line()`, you will need to add `color` within the `aes()` function for `geom_abline()` to make sure you "see" the name in the legend.  The problem here is that when you supply *either* `slope` or `interecept` to `geom_abline()`, any other aesthetics will be ignored.

To get `ggplot2` to *use* the `color` aesthetic, *slope, intercept, and color need to be included inside `aes()`*:

```
geom_abline(data=..., aes(slope=..., intercept=..., color=...))
```

This means, you should create a new dataframe and apply this to `geom_abline()` to get this to work.

```
abdf <- data.frame(
  slope=0,
  intercept=varC_coef[1])
```

Note that I changed slope to be `0` here because as pointed out in the comments, even with slope at `-0.004`, the number is below the visible area of the plot and the plot does not automatically scale with `geom_abline()` since the dataset is effectively understood to be infinity in both x and y directions.

I changed the color in `cols` so that the line is black.  In the code, you'll also want to change `key_glyph` to `"path"`, because the default value changes the legend key.

```
cols <- c("varA" = "#D55E00", "varB" = "#0072B2", "varC" = "black")

ggplot() +
  geom_line(
    data=df1, linewidth=1,
    aes(x=year, y=varA, color="varA")) +
  geom_line(
    data=df2, linewidth=1,
    aes(x=year, y=varB/100, color="varB")) +
  geom_abline(
    data=abdf, linewidth=1, key_glyph="path",
    aes(slope=slope, intercept=intercept, color="varC")) +
  scale_color_manual(
    name=NULL, values=cols,
    labels=c("Variable A", "Variable B", "Variable C"))
```

[image]

#### Bonus: "Grammar of Graphics" Answer

All this aside, the better way to get the plot you are drawing that is more aligned with the philosophy of `ggplot2` and the grammar of graphics would be to combine your datasets first, then plot with a single `geom_line()` command.  Full code would be the following:

```
df2$varB <- df2$varB/100  # doesn't preserve the original data, but more straightforward
df <- merge(df1, df2a)
dfnew <- tidyr::pivot_longer(
  data=df, cols=-year,
  names_to="variable", values_to="val")

varC_coef <- coef(lm(varA*0.2 ~ year, data = df1))
abdf <- data.frame(slope=0, intercept=varC_coef[1], variable="varC")
cols <- c("varA" = "#D55E00", "varB" = "#0072B2", "varC" = "black")

g3 <- ggplot(dfnew, aes(x=year, y=val, color=variable)) +
  geom_line(linewidth=1) +
  geom_abline(
    data=abdf,
    aes(color=variable, slope=slope, intercept=intercept),
    linewidth=1, key_glyph="path") +
  scale_color_manual(
    values=cols,
    labels=c("Variable A", "Variable B", "Variable C"))
```